# My two Juniper J2320 Routers can't ping each other

Tags: router, juniper, juniper-junos

**FINALLY GOT IT TO WORK**

I have two J2320s connected by an Ethernet cable.

The cable is connected to both in their ge-0/0/1 unit 0 interfaces.

One is 192.168.2.5/24 and the other is 192.168.2.13/24

Pings don't work yet both interfaces are up.

Neither Router can ping my Laptop when I had it connected either.

my configurations:

**Router1**

```
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.2.5/24 primary
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.2.5/24 preferred
```

**Router2**

```
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.2.13/24 primary
set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.2.13/24 peferred
```

then I commit them

Pings don't work.

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the router configurations.

Comment: You need to give all the router configurations. We can't guess what else you have configured that may cause a problem.

Comment: This is all I have configured.

Comment: Both routers can ping themselves but not each other.

Comment: The only other configuration is I gave both the same root-authentication password

Comment: You should post an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to define security-zones and policies.
Configure security zone on all interfaces and default policy for that zone which would permit ping.

Comment: Are Juniper routers supposed to be configured with security zones? I know the Security Devices do.

Comment: If you want to use box as router without NAT or firewall features you can delete zones:
#delete security
#set security forwarding-options family mpls mode packet-based

Comment: Hello, well I finally got pings to work, I appreciate it.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you post those lines of configuration out fully for my reference?

Comment: @Datagram.Network , The statement #set security forwarding-options family mpls mode packet-based - did the magic ! Thank you !