# Juniper vMX Routers can't ping each other in GNS3

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, gns3, juniper-mx

I have a couple of VMX Routers setup in GNS3 that are directly connected on their interface, ge-0/0/2 and they can't ping each other. PFB configuration. I can't seem to find the problem!

**UPDATE: Added all the GNS3 topology details at the bottom**

### R1 Config

```
root@R1> show configuration             
## Last commit: 2020-09-11 14:29:18 UTC by root
version 14.1R1.10;
system {
    host-name R1;
    root-authentication {
    encrypted-password "$1$MJbVQp1z$J1HQasM0nRJXAbvMhUR/R."; ## SECRET-DATA
    }
    syslog {
    user * {
        any emergency;
    }
    file messages {
        any notice;
        authorization info;
    }
    file interactive-commands {
        interactive-commands any;
    }
    }
}
interfaces {
    ge-0/0/2 {
    unit 0 {
        family inet {               
            address 192.168.0.1/24;
        }
    }
    }
}

root@R1>
```

### R2 Config

```
root@R2> show configuration 
## Last commit: 2020-09-11 10:12:59 UTC by root
version 14.1R1.10;
system {
    host-name R2;
    root-authentication {
    encrypted-password "$1$5Aoo5B1X$SXlXzKs384GMYsTXnBDmH0"; ## SECRET-DATA
    }
    syslog {
    user * {
        any emergency;
    }
    file messages {
        any notice;
        authorization info;
    }
    file interactive-commands {
        interactive-commands any;
    }
    }
}
interfaces {
    ge-0/0/2 {
    unit 0 {
        family inet {               
            address 192.168.0.2/24;
        }
    }
    }
}

root@R2>
```

As you can see, it's a very basic configuration -- just an IP address on either end of the directly connected interface. I even tried to do a packet capture using wireshark via GNS3, and couldn't see a single packet on the wire!

However, a route is definitely present on either end. I also am not learning any ARP entries on the interface.

```
root@R1> show interfaces terse | match ge-0/0/2 
ge-0/0/2                up    up
ge-0/0/2.0              up    up   inet     192.168.0.1/24  


root@R2> show interfaces terse | match ge-0/0/2 
ge-0/0/2                up    up
ge-0/0/2.0              up    up   inet     192.168.0.2/24  

root@R1> show arp interface ge-0/0/2 

root@R1> show arp interface ge-0/0/2.0  

root@R1> ping 192.168.0.1 
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.997 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.116 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.116/1.056/1.997/0.941 ms

root@R1> ping 192.168.0.2    
PING 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 192.168.0.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss

root@R1> show route                     

inet.0: 2 destinations, 2 routes (2 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

192.168.0.0/24     *[Direct/0] 00:34:45
                > via ge-0/0/2.0
192.168.0.1/32     *[Local/0] 00:34:45
                  Local via ge-0/0/2.0

root@R2> show route 

inet.0: 2 destinations, 2 routes (2 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

192.168.0.0/24     *[Direct/0] 04:51:35
                > via ge-0/0/2.0
192.168.0.2/32     *[Local/0] 04:51:35
                  Local via ge-0/0/2.0
```

---

### Version info -- both routers

Both routers are running the exact same image:

```
root@R1> show version brief 
Hostname: R1
Model: vmx
Junos: 14.1R1.10
JUNOS Base OS Software Suite [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Base OS boot [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Crypto Software Suite [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Online Documentation [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Kernel Software Suite [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Packet Forwarding Engine Support (M320) [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Packet Forwarding Engine Support (M/T/EX Common) [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Routing Software Suite [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Runtime Software Suite [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services AACL PIC package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services Application Level Gateway [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services Application Level Gateway (xlp64) [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services Application Level Gateway (xlr64) [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS AppId Services PIC Package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services AppId PIC package (xlr64) [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Border Gateway Function PIC package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services Captive Portal and Content Delivery PIC package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services HTTP Content Management PIC package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services HTTP Content Management PIC package (xlr64) [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS IDP Services PIC Package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Packet Forwarding Engine Trio Simulation Package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services JFLOW PIC package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services JFLOW PIC package (xlp64) [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services LL-PDF PIC package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS MobileNext PIC package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS MobileNext PIC package (xlr64) [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services Mobile Subscriber Service Container package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services Mobile Subscriber Service PIC package (xlr64) [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services NAT PIC package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services NAT PIC package (xlp64) [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services NAT PIC package (xlr64) [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services PTSP PIC package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services RPM PIC package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services RPM PIC package (xlp64) [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services Stateful Firewall PIC package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services Stateful Firewall PIC package (xlp64) [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services Stateful Firewall PIC package (xlr64) [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS BSG PIC package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services Crypto Base PIC package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services Crypto Base PIC package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services Crypto Base PIC package(xlr64) [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services IPSec PIC package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services IPSec PIC package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services IPSec PIC(xlr64) package [14.1R1.10]
JUNOS Services SSL PIC package [14.1R1.10]
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Troubleshooting:

Tried this link's suggestion: [My two Juniper J2320 Routers can't ping each other](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/44827/my-two-juniper-j2320-routers-cant-ping-each-other)

Don't even have the options:

```
root@R2# set security forwarding-options
                  ^
syntax error.
root@R2# set security forwarding-optionsfamily            
                  ^
syntax error.
root@R2# set security forwarding-optionsfamilympls
                  ^
syntax error.
root@R2# set security forwarding-optionsfamilymplsmode
                  ^
syntax error.
root@R2# set security forwarding-optionsfamilymplsmodepacket-based
                  ^
syntax error.
root@R2# set security forwarding-optionsfamilymplsmodepacket-based   
                  ^
syntax error.
root@R2# set security forwarding                                     
                  ^
syntax error.
root@R2# set security forwarding                                    
                  ^
syntax error.
root@R2# set security ?            
Possible completions:
> alarms               Configure security alarms
+ apply-groups         Groups from which to inherit configuration data
+ apply-groups-except  Don't inherit configuration data from these groups
> authentication-key-chains  Authentication key chain configuration
> group-vpn            Group VPN configuration
> idp                  IDP configuration
> ike                  IKE configuration
> ipsec                IPSec configuration
> log                  Configure auditable security logs
> pki                  PKI service configuration
> ssh-known-hosts      SSH known host list
> traceoptions         Trace options for IPSec key management
[edit]
root@R2# delete security          
warning: statement not found

[edit]
root@R2#
```

---

### Update: Adding GNS3 Topology & Config

Here's the topology:

[image: Topology 1]
[image: Topology 2]

### Here's the template settings in GNS3:

[image: Config1]
[image: Config2]
[image: Config3]
[image: Config4]
[image: Config5]

Comment: I think your problem is with the GNS3 configuration, not with the configuration of the vMXes themselves.

Comment: Could we see the GNS3 topology?  It might point to things with the vMXs.

Comment: @JeffWheeler updated topology and GNS3 settings for more information

Comment: @JordanHead updated topology and GNS3 settings for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the interfaces you have connected in GNS3, `em2 ---- em2` are actually named `ge-0/0/0` by the vMX nodes.  Try `edit interfaces` `rename ge-0/0/2 to ge-0/0/0` on both vMX, commit, and check for connectivity; or in GNS3 connect the `em4` interfaces to each-other and check if the current vMX configs work.

The documentation around GNS3/vMX interface naming is pretty confusing.  It tells you the first two interfaces are for internal connections, and that really means, eth0/em0 and eth1/em1 are used by JunOS for fxp0 and fxp1 (or whatever they're named by the JunOS image you're running.)  The first interface usable to you is `ge-0/0/0` and that one is called eth2 or em2 by GNS3.

Excerpt from the GNS3 vMX & vQFX [reference](https://docs.gns3.com/docs/how-to-guides/importing-vmx-and-vqfx-into-gns3/):

```
    Eth0 = the management interface (fxp0)
    Eth1 = internal interface (unusable to us)
    Eth2 = ge-0/0/0
    Eth3 = ge-0/0/1
    Eth4 = ge-0/0/2
    …
    Eth11 = ge-0/0/9

Thus, if you wanted to connect ge-0/0/0 on two vMX instances to each other, you’d connect Eth2 on both VMs to each other.
```

Comment: Bingo, this is exactly the thing I was going to say.

Comment: That's exactly what it was, Jeff! Also, thanks for your help, @JordanHead